# Manipulating elements outside the scope of a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am currently working on a report which includes some input elements for data filtering and a table displaying the corresponding data from a collection.

I have following Addy Osmani's [subviews solution](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#commonproblems%20subviews%20solution) for my subviews. So I have

- a report view which has:

  - header subview
  - toggle subview
  - table subview

The toggle subview is basically an anchor element that has a triangle background and flips based on the class.

The toggle subview has two tasks

1. listen to click events and flip it's self by changing the class.
2. Manipulate the parent view's (report view) class for shown and hidden states.

My question is where should the logic for changing the report view's classes live in? 
in the subview? or the parent view? 
and if it's in the parent view how do I call the method

- directly by passing parentView as a parameter and from the subview this.parentView.toggleReport()
- again passing the parentView as a parameter and triggering an event on the parent view.
- just manipulate the dom outside the scope of the toggle view.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the parent view listen for a custom event on the toggle view, and act accordingly.

Inside the parent view:

```
this.toggleView.on('toggle', this.toggleReport, this);
```

Inside the toggle view where you flip your own class also throw in a:

```
this.trigger('toggle'); // or this.trigger('toggle', stateOfTheToggle);
```

The other option is to use a `Model` to represent the state of the toggle, and share that between the parent view and the toggle view... and just bind to events on that.